# In my app, I am taking image and audio file from internal storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

In my app, I am getting an image and audio file from internal storage. It works fine in **micromax funbook tab 4.2.2 (jellybean)** but when I tried to run the same apk in **Nexus 7** it doesn't work.

This is my code
 internroot=

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/AmritaLeveledReader/"+Frag+"/books/book/book_"+position;`

Comment: add run time permission if android version is marshmallow

Comment: i am new to android so plz explan how?@ pravin

Comment: go through http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/  and add Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: thanku ..  it works :)